# Do we have to show that the integral is convergent

Tags: calculus

I have seen many proofs that calculate by using some substitutions and arriving at some simple equalities that show $$\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos x)dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$

They do the following:
$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos x)dx = -\int_{\pi/2}^0\ln(\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}-x))dx = \int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\sin x)dx$$

$$2I=I+I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos x)dx + \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin x)dx= \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin x \cos x)dx$$$$=\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln\left(\frac{\sin(2x)}{2}\right)dx$$$$= -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2 + \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(2x))dx=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2 + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi} \ln(\sin x)dx$$$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin x)dx + \int_{\pi/2}^{\pi} \ln(\sin x)dx\right)$$$$=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin x)dx + \int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\cos x)dx\right)$$$$2I=-\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2 + \frac{1}{2}\cdot2I$$$$I=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos x)dx = -\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$$

My question is as follows:
In many calculus courses, to show that the result is the number we manipulate as in here and arrive at a more solvable equation, we had also to show that these things (integrals, limits, etc.) converge. Is the proof enough if we do not show that the integral converges? If it is not enough, how can we show that the integral converges?

Comment: In this case I think everything goes through just fine without having to assume the integral converges - if you'd like you can see it as if each improper integral is the limit of a proper integral and we're just using operations on the convergent integrals in the limit while leaving the limit implicit.

Comment: Actually, I think I may have made an error: when I was looking through I overlooked an interchange of limits which I think requires the original limit to exist in the general case. (trying to use the Moore-Osgood theorem)  So I think in this case we would justify that the limit $\lim_{b \to \frac\pi2^-}\int_0^b \ln \cos x dx$ exists because it's monotone decreasing in $b$, since $\ln \cos x \leq 0.$ So either it converges or it goes to negative infinity, and either way it's enough to justify the required operations

Comment: You are correct. In this case, the integer can possibly be $-\onfty,$ and the equation $2I=K+I$ has $-\infty$ as a solution.

Comment: As for the question in the general case: yes, you would normally need to justify that all quantities involved are well-defined and finite. Otherwise, you can easily end up in scenarios such as setting a previously finite integral equal to the difference of two nonconvergent integrals, potentially rendering any further calculations suspect. As for *how* you show the convergence of the integrals, it depends entirely on what specifically they are, so nothing more can be said here that covers all cases.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the only singularity is $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$. Since
\begin{eqnarray} 
&&\lim_{x\to(\frac\pi2)^-}(\frac\pi2-x)^{\frac12}\ln\cos x\\
&=&\lim_{x\to(\frac\pi2)^-}\frac{\ln\cos x}{(\frac\pi2-x)^{-\frac12}}\\
&=&2\lim_{x\to(\frac\pi2)^-}\frac{\sin x}{(\frac\pi2-x)^{-\frac32}\cos x}\\
&=&2\lim_{x\to(\frac\pi2)^-}\frac{(\frac\pi2-x)^{\frac32}\sin x}{\cos x}\\
&=&2\lim_{x\to(\frac\pi2)^-}(\frac\pi2-x)^{\frac12}\frac{(\frac\pi2-x)\sin x}{\cos (\frac\pi2-x)}\\
&=&0,
\end{eqnarray}
the integral converges.